# Codeigniter Values not passing from view to controller in Form submit in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I've a view in which a bootstrap modal is shown when a link is clicked. I've put a form submit in this modal. The fields inside bootstrap modal is filled through javascript. My problem is that when i submit the form, I'm not getting the values in POST in controller. I couldn't find where I've went wrong.

Here is my code:

View:

```
<script>
function showmodal(internaltt,indusid,eqptname,eqptmake,priority)
{
var complaintid=internaltt;
document.getElementById("nhiddenevent").value = complaintid;
document.getElementById("ninternaltt").value = complaintid;
document.getElementById("nindusid").value = indusid;
document.getElementById("faulty").value = eqptname;
document.getElementById("faultymake").value = eqptmake;
document.getElementById("priority").value = priority; 
$('#responsiveshow').modal('show');
}
</script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
TT Number
</th>
<th>
Indus ID
</th>
<th>
Date
</th>
<th>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
if(isset($list) && !empty($list))
{
foreach($list as $complaints)
{

?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $complaints->complaint_id;?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo $complaints->indus_id;?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo $complaints->created_date;?>
</td>
<td>
<a href="" onClick="showmodal(<?php echo $complaints->complaint_id;?>,'<?php echo $complaints->indus_id;?>','<?php echo $complaints->faulty_equipment;?>','<?php echo $complaints->faulty_eqpt_make;?>','<?php echo $complaints->priority;?>')" data-toggle="modal">View </a>
</td>
</tr>
<!------------ BEGIN MODAL ------------------------- -->
<!-- /.modal -->
<div id="responsiveshow" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Complaints</h4>
</div>
<div>
<?php 
echo form_open("index.php/complaints/registerindus"); ?>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="scroller" style="height:300px" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">TT Number</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="TT Number" class="form-control" name="ninternaltt" id="ninternaltt"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Indus TT Number</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Indus TT Number" class="form-control" name="nindustt" id="nindustt"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Indus ID</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Indus ID" class="form-control" name="nindusid" id="nindusid"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Faulty Equipment</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="TT Number" class="form-control" name="faulty" id="faulty"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Faulty Equipment Make</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="TT Number" class="form-control" name="faultymake" id="faultymake"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Priority</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="TT Number" class="form-control" name="priority" id="priority"/>
<input type="hidden" name="nhiddenevent" id="nhiddenevent">
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Close</button>
<input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Update Indus ID">
</div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
<!-- --------------- END MODAL ------------ -->
<?php
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Complaints extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();

$this->load->model('complaints_model');
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function registerindus()
{
$internaltt=$this->input->post('ninternaltt'); //here m not getting the values from view
$industt=$this->input->post('nindustt'); //here m not getting the values from view
$eturn=$this->complaints_model->updateIndusTT($internaltt,$industt);
if($return)
{
$this->index(); 
}
else
{
$this->listunregistered();
}
}   
}
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this problem.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: check out  form action path, use site_url() for route

Comment: Also check the `$eturn=` and `if($return)` in your Controller.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<?php echo form_open("index.php/complaints/registerindus"); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo form_open("complaints/registerindus"); ?>
```

Here's a simple example: `echo form_open('email/send');`

The above example would create a form that points to your base URL plus the "email/send" URI segments, like this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/email/send" />
```

Also debug your code by echoing post values in controller function

then a typo here

```
$eturn=$this->complaints_model->updateIndusTT($internaltt,$industt);
```

should be

```
$return=$this->complaints_model->updateIndusTT($internaltt,$industt);
```

Comment: when I changed `<?php echo form_open("index.php/complaints/registerindus"); ?>` to `<?php echo form_open("complaints/registerindus"); ?>` I'm getting an error: `Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.`

Comment: then try to remove index.php first